# Display Column Names when NULL value found

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table below:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7
=====================================================
XYZ             GH      JY              IOP 
GH      TY                                      HGF
                TR              OPY
```

I want to write a SQL query  which will check for `NULL` values in each row and display the column name which has `NULL` values into a new column named 'Missing values'.

So the output will look like:

```
Missing Value 
=============
Col2,Col5,Col7
Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6
Col1,Col2,Col4,Col6,Col7
```

Comment: Did you try it by your own?

Comment: I tried using CASE statement which is working fine, but want i have write 

SELECT CASE WHEN COL1 is NULL and COL2 is NULL... then "Missing COl1,Col2..."

Comment: You will need to construct either a nested query/subquery on data dictionary and your data or use PL/SQL which may be a bit more straight forward.

Comment: Can you help me out with the nested query/subquery. Donot want to use PL/SQL

Comment: you can also make a user defined aggregate function in oracle.

Comment: is there a primary key? or are all columns possible to become null?

Comment: all the columns are nullable

Answer (score 1):

the structure should work

```
select decode( col1, null, 'col1 ' ) 
|| decode( col2, null, 'col2 ' )
|| decode( col3, null, 'col3 ' ) 
from mytable
```

Comment: Yes, tried a similar thing using CASE statement and got that working, but the problem is that i have 12 columns, so will need to write many such statement for 12 columns.

Comment: yes - you will need one decode per column, but that is all - no other permutations - like you showed in your other comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the results to be comma-separated, you might try this variation on @Randy's answer:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR
    (
        DECODE(COL1, NULL, ',COL1')
        ||
        DECODE(COL2, NULL, ',COL2')
        ||
        DECODE(COL3, NULL, ',COL3')
        ||
        DECODE(COL4, NULL, ',COL4'),
        2
    )
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE
```